# Deleting model instance from frontend

Tags: django, django-models

I want to add a button to my list of actors. This button should be able to delete that instance.

**I tried the following but it won't work, what am I doing wrong?:**

```
<ul>{% for actor in actors %}
<li>Name: {{ actor.name }}
<br> 
Wage: {{ actor.wage }} 
<a href="{% actor.delete() %}">DELETE</a></li>
<br><br>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: you can not use method calls - `delete()` in template. You need to create view to delete actor, add url to `urls.py` and call that url in href value.

Comment: Could I add the delete method to the current view or should I create an entirely new one?

Comment: Django template framework is not designed to include business logic. **Especially** database logic. You should rethink your design patterns. For basic CRUD use *generic editing views* which are provided by Django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.DeleteView

Comment: @JamesKolber new one. Read the docs and try tutorial on django. These are basics. You will struggle a lot before you build something :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, thanks everyone.

I simply created a new url that references a function in my views.py that looks like this:

```
def del_actor(request, actor_id):
actor = Actor.objects.get(id=actor_id)
Actor.objects.get(id=actor_id).delete()
return HttpResponseRedirect('/scenes/actor/')
```